# Why are these equations equal to a constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am reading this part of a research paper

[image]

where the author states that the left hand side of equations (12) and (13) must be equal to a constant. However I could not understand the explanation he gives.
Does anyone know what the author means for why the equations are equal to a constant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation (13) can be written on a simpler form :
$$f(r)=g(t)$$
which is true any $r$ and any $t$.

Given a value $t=t_1$ then $f(r)=g(t_1)$ any $r$. Hense $f(r)$ doesn't change while $r$ changes. Thus $f(r)=\text{constant}$.

Similary, $g(t)=\text{constant}$. Both constant are equal since $f(r)=g(t)$
$$f(r)=g(t)=C$$
Of course $C$ can be any constant.

So you get a system of two equations  : $\begin{cases} f(r)=C \\ g(t)=C \end{cases}$

in which $C$ is any constant. This means that $C$ is a parameter.

The wording of the question lacks definition of functions and respective variables. Nevertheless, if my interpretation is correct, the argument is summarized below :

[image]

Comment: But the problem is that if we equate the left hand side of both (12) and (13) and remove the terms that appear on both sides then both sides only depend on $r$ so they are not constant. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: ''both sides only depend on $r$ so they are not constant" . Instead of "depends on" better say "is a function of". In the present case, the correct expression is : ''both sides are function of $r$ only and this function is the constant function.

Comment: To make it clear (I hope), the argument is summarized in addition to my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that transitivity of equality implies the LHS of both equations are equal.

Now imagine you could vary $r$ and $t$ independently to any values you would please. The two LHS's should change (likely in a continuous manner), but must equal each other no matter what values you pick.

The only way this would be possible is if both LHS's equalled the same constant.

Comment: I understand that they are equal to each other but I am not sure why they are equal to a constant because if you very $r$ or $t$ then the equations change so how could they be constant?

Comment: The expressions should change. But if an expression that should change does not change when you vary something arbitrarily, it has to be constant.

Comment: Example: Consider the expression $3x-(x+2x)=\frac{t}{2t}-\frac{1}{2}$ , which holds for all $x$ and $t$ in the domains of the LHS and RHS respectively.

Comment: But both sides in Eq.(14) depend on $r$ so we have $g(r)=f(r)=2k$

Comment: how is that possible

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$? The LHS in (12) and (13) are equal to a constant. Some terms cancel because they appear in both expressions.

Comment: This is what I am confused about. First we noticed that the right hand sides of both equations (12) and (13) are equal. So we equate the left hand sides of both equations (12) and (13) and remove the terms that appear on both equations. We end up with two equations that depend on $r$ only. I don't get why they must be equal to a constant because its not like one equation only depend on $r$ and the other only depends $t$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the identity $f(r)=g(t)$ for all $r$ and $t$, then the functions must be constant. If you want, simply take derivatives on both sides with respect say to $r$. Then $f'(r)=0$ because $g$ does not depend on $t$. Hence, $f$ is constant and the same happens to $g$.